# how can search the userinteraction option of uibutton is YES or NO

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, nsmutablearray, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to implement gesture recognizer type application with `UIButtons`. The `UIButtons` are arranged in a `NSMutableArray`.Initially set the user interaction option of all `UIButtons` are `NO`. Occurring of an another button event(`setEvent:`) change the user interaction option to `YES` (Only one button's userinteraction option set at a time) from array of `UIButtons`.  Now i want to search the array for check the `UIButton`  *user interaction* property is `YES`.

If anybody know please help me.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (UIButton *button in yourButtonsArray) {
    if (button.userInteractionEnabled) {
        ....
    }
}
```